# Running a Spring MVC Webapp on Tomcat9

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run a Spring MVC webapp on Tomcat9. I'm able to deploy it using Maven to Tomcat. I'm also able to access the index.jsp from FireFox. However, my index.jsp does a simple re-direct to /customer/list and that results in a 404 Not Found error. I've done RequestMapping on the controller class (for /customer) and GetMapping on a method in that class (for /list). The same code works when I run it as a dynamic web project in Eclipse with embedded Tomcat. But, when I re-wrote it as a Maven project, I'm only able to reach index.jsp, but the re-direct in index.jsp fails. Code below ...

**index.jsp**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/customer/list"); %>
```

**spring.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.crm" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/hibernate?currentSchema=web_crm" />
        <property name="user" value="hbstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="hbstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  
    
    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.crm.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
    
</beans>
```

**CustomerController.java**

```
package com.luv2code.crm.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.luv2code.crm.entity.Customer;
import com.luv2code.crm.service.CustomerService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model m) {
        
        m.addAttribute("customerList", customerService.getCustomers());
        
        return "list-customers";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model m) {
        
        m.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "customer-form";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveCustomer")
    public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer c) {
        
        customerService.saveCustomer(c);
        return "redirect:/customer/list";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("customerId") int i, Model m) {
        
        m.addAttribute("customer", customerService.getCustomer(i));
        return "customer-form";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteCustomer(@RequestParam("customerId") int i) {

        customerService.deleteCustomer(i);
        return "redirect:/customer/list";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String searchCustomers(@RequestParam("theSearchName") String s, Model m) {
        
        m.addAttribute("customerList", customerService.searchCustomers(s));
        return "list-customers";
    }
    
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
  <artifactId>web_crm</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>web_crm Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    
    <spring.version>5.3.5</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>web_crm</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/web_crm</path>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>password</password>
                <update>true</update>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
    <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
         <id>internal.repo</id>
         <name>Internal repo</name>
         <!-- <url>file:///home/tushar/Software/apache-tomcat-9.0.43/webapps</url> -->
         <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
       </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

**Directory structure**

```
$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── com
    │   │   │   └── luv2code
    │   │   │       └── crm
    │   │   │           ├── controller
    │   │   │           │   └── CustomerController.java
    │   │   │           ├── dao
    │   │   │           │   ├── CustomerDAOImpl.java
    │   │   │           │   └── CustomerDAO.java
    │   │   │           ├── entity
    │   │   │           │   └── Customer.java
    │   │   │           ├── service
    │   │   │           │   ├── CustomerServiceImpl.java
    │   │   │           │   └── CustomerService.java
    │   │   │           └── test
    │   │   │               └── TestDBServlet.java
    │   │   └── hibernate.cfg.xml
    │   ├── resources
    │   └── webapp
    │       ├── index.jsp
    │       ├── resources
    │       │   └── css
    │       │       ├── add-customer-style.css
    │       │       └── style.css
    │       └── WEB-INF
    │           ├── classes
    │           │   └── hibernate.cfg.xml
    │           ├── spring.cfg.xml
    │           ├── view
    │           │   ├── customer-form.jsp
    │           │   └── list-customers.jsp
    │           └── web.xml
    └── test

19 directories, 17 files
```

Comment: Can you share the picture of your project structure as well?

Comment: you might want to try out the steps explained in this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Comment: @zawarudo , added dir tree structure as requested. thanks.

Comment: @MaikSettels , yes, I based it on those instructions. It allows me to hit the index.jsp. But, redirect from index.jsp fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this.

In pom.xml, you can specify a deployment path. By default, it is the same as your artifactId. Then, when you specify the url mapping in web.xml, it should be relative to the deployment path. In my web.xml, I was including the deployment path component as well in the url mapping. Hence, it was not working.

I changed the url mapping to / and it works fine.